# How to install Google-Recaptcha from npm

Tags: npm, google-api, recaptcha

I'm implementing recaptcha in my webapp in some forms.

I already implement my backend part and i'm right now trying to install recapatcha api.

Unfornatly, I do not find an official package in npm from google.

Should I use the package **[googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)** that include recpatcha or 
should I include this script :

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

I'm asking this because I build my script files ( including all vendors coming from npm ) with **Webpack**.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use google reCAPTCHA v3 without any npm hassle.

Register from here : https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

Then for front-end:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key"></script>
  <script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         ...
      });
  });
  </script>
```

In v3 you can define your actions or pass your `intent`

```
  <script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'homepage'});
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this really answers the question. The question seems to be centered around how one might go about installing the library via npm, and if that's not possible then what is the best alternative. This answer, by contrast, seems to be centered on how to use the recaptcha library once loaded via a script tag, and therefore sidesteps the main thrust of the question. The questioner clearly already knows that the script tag is an option, so I don't think this helps very much. Are you implying that no library in NPM would work? Is a script tag better than an npm install for some reason?